# How to solve error with rootless docker in github actions self hosted runner: write /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range: invalid argument: unknown

Tags: docker, github-actions

I'm trying to run the github actions runner with rootless docker, and it mostly works, except for the following error when using the v2 build-push action.

```
Error: buildx call failed with: error: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: write sysctl key net.ipv4.ping_group_range: write /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ping_group_range: invalid argument: unknown
```

I have already tried to apply this fix for ping: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#routing-ping-packets

But that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for this is adding driver: docker to the setup-buildx action.

```
      - uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
        with:
          driver: docker
```

for more info see: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/292

And on how to set up github actions with rootless docker in the first place: [How to enable non-docker actions to access docker-created files on my self hosted github actions runner? (rootless docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137419/how-to-enable-non-docker-actions-to-access-docker-created-files-on-my-self-hoste)